# How to find the index location of dropped item into Silverlight ListBoxDragDropTarget

Tags: silverlight

I have a silverlight ListBox that is contained in a ListBoxDragDropTarget.  I am listening to the Drop event of the DDT, but I don't know how to find the index of the drop action.  i.e. I want to know at which index spot the user dropped the items into my ListBox.  On the UI when I'm dragging over the ListBox, I can see a line indicating the spot that I'm hovering over, but after dropping, I don't know how to get the drop location information from the drop event.

Answer (score 0):

Given the following Xaml:

```xml
<Grid x:Name="ListBoxDragDropTarget"
      Background="Gold"
      AllowDrop="True"
      Drop="ListBoxDragDropTarget_Drop">
    <ListBox x:Name="MyListBox" Margin="50">
        <ListBoxItem Content="Item 1" />
        <ListBoxItem Content="Item 2" />
        <ListBoxItem Content="Item 3" />
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

If you want to know the ListBoxItem on which the user dropped the items you can use `e.GetPosition` to get the position of the mouse and `VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates` for hit testing:

```cs
private void ListBoxDragDropTarget_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    Point position = e.GetPosition(this.ListBoxDragDropTarget);

    var hits = VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates(position, this.ListBoxDragDropTarget);

    ListBoxItem dropElement = hits.FirstOrDefault(i => i is ListBoxItem) as ListBoxItem;

    if (dropElement != null)
    {
        // Do something with the dropElement... or if you want the index use ItemContainerGenerator
        int index = this.MyListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(dropElement);
    }
}
```